# How to remove Mayavi toolbar in python using code

Tags: python, hide, toolbar, mayavi

I have several Mayavi plots that I am combining in a single window (along the lines of the [documentation](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_multiple_mlab_scene_models.html)), and it would be much better if I could get rid of the toolbars in all of them. While it's possible to to right-click each of the toolbars to have them disappear, I would like to code them to disappear instead. A command like `scene.hide_toolbar()` would be ideal. I've dug around in the TraitsUI package a bit to no avail... anybody know how to make it go away?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Handler` to modify UI, the following code works with ETS_TOOLKIT=qt4. Add the `DisableToolbarHandler` class to the code `multiple_mlab_scene_models.py`, and show the UI by `m.edit_traits(handler=DisableToolbarHandler())`.

```
class DisableToolbarHandler(Handler):
    def position(self, info):
        for name in ["scene1", "scene2"]:
            editor = info.ui.get_editors(name)[0]
            editor._scene._tool_bar.setVisible(False)

m = MyDialog()
m.edit_traits(handler=DisableToolbarHandler())
```

The windows shows as:

[image]

Comment: That worked like a charm! Any idea how to remove the toolbar for a single figure (e.g., a figure created using mlab.figure())?

Comment: On a figure, this can easily be done like so:

    fig = mlab.figure(1)
    fig.scene.scene_editor._tool_bar.setVisible(False)