# Removing toolbar from mayavi scene

Tags: python, toolbar, mayavi

Is it possible to remove/hide the standard toolbar which is created by default when you plot something with mayavi? I found this: [How to remove Mayavi toolbar in python using code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444458/how-to-remove-mayavi-toolbar-in-python-using-code)

But I don't understand where I should insert this code. Is there something easier like mlab.toolbar.setVisible(False)?

Comment: Maybe a minimum working example will help for your question. I understand it may not be obvious from the answer you linked, but maybe we can help if you show us the code you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt4'
os.environ['QT_API'] = 'pyqt5' 

from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, MlabSceneModel, SceneEditor
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from main import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
from traitsui.api import Handler


class Visualization(HasTraits):
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
    def update_plot(self):
        self.scene.mlab.test_points3d()

    view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                 height=250, width=300, show_label=False),
            resizable=True  # We need this to resize with the parent widget
            )


class DisableToolbarHandler(Handler):
    def position(self, info):
        editor = info.ui.get_editors('scene')[0]
        editor._scene._tool_bar.setVisible(False)


class MayaviQWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.visualization = Visualization()
        self.ui = self.visualization.edit_traits(handler=DisableToolbarHandler(), kind='subpanel').control
        layout.addWidget(self.ui)
        self.ui.setParent(self)


class Action(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Action, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.splitter.setSizes([100, 300])
        self.splitter_2.setSizes([400, 100])

        container = QWidget()
        mayavi_widget = MayaviQWidget(container)
        self.Layout.addWidget(mayavi_widget)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    action = Action()
    action.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @roflcopter122 hello, I have integrated a mayavi 3d plot into a gui which was made with pyqt5, and the Mayavi toolbar was removed using code. But when I Converting it into .exe-file with cx_Freeze, The same problem was encountered:"no traitsui.toolkits plugin found for toolkit qt4".Can you tell me about your solution? Thank you very much!

Comment: The only solution to handle this issue was to downgrade pyqt5 to pyqt4 and all other packages which have dependencies to pyqt5. Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

On a figure, this can easily be done like so:

```
fig = mlab.figure(1)
fig.scene.scene_editor._tool_bar.setVisible(False)
```