# How can i hide/remove the mayavi pipeline?

Tags: python-3.x, mayavi, mayavi.mlab

Here is my code i want to hide the mayavi pipeline, here i am using class DisableToolbarHandler for to hide the mayavi whole toolbar,but its gives the X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter).
I don't have any idea about it,so can any one please guide me how to remove/hide the mayavi pipeline

```
import numpy as np

from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, Button, \
    on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View, Item, HSplit, Group
from traitsui.api import  Handler
from mayavi import mlab
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MlabSceneModel, SceneEditor


class MyDialog(HasTraits):

    scene1 = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())
    scene2 = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    button1 = Button('Redraw')
    button2 = Button('Redraw')

    @on_trait_change('button1')
    def redraw_scene1(self):
        self.redraw_scene(self.scene1)

    @on_trait_change('button2')
    def redraw_scene2(self):
        self.redraw_scene(self.scene2)

    def redraw_scene(self, scene):
        # Notice how each mlab call points explicitely to the figure it
        # applies to.
        mlab.clf(figure=scene.mayavi_scene)
        x, y, z, s = np.random.random((4, 100))
        mlab.points3d(x, y, z, s, figure=scene.mayavi_scene)

    # The layout of the dialog created
    view = View(HSplit(
                  Group(
                       Item('scene1',
                            editor=SceneEditor(), height=250,
                            width=300),
                       'button1',
                       show_labels=False,
                  ),
                  Group(
                       Item('scene2',
                            editor=SceneEditor(), height=250,
                            width=300, show_label=False),
                       'button2',
                       show_labels=False,
                  ),
                ),
                resizable=True,
                )

class DisableToolbarHandler(Handler):
    def position(self, info):
        for name in ["scene1", "scene2"]:
            editor = info.ui.get_editors(name)[0]
            editor._scene._tool_bar.setVisible(False)

m = MyDialog()
m.edit_traits(handler=DisableToolbarHandler())
```

Comment: Do you mean the mayavi icon on the toolbar? The whole toolbar?

Comment: It is like x , y,  z and some other options  i want to remove whole tool bar

Comment: This is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15444458/how-to-remove-mayavi-toolbar-in-python-using-code

Comment: i.e not working in my code